# Usage of static properties in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

I am using a static class shared between different Azure functions. If I configure this static class in one Azure function can I then expect it to keep this setting next time it is being used from another Azure Function? They live in the same Azure Function App.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if both invocations happen on the same instance (server running your Function App). There might be multiple instances running at the same time (scale out under load) or over time (one instance gets recycled, another created).

Answer (score 0):

> If I configure this static class in one Azure function can I then
>   expect it to keep this setting next time it is being used from another
>   Azure Function?

Only if this another Azure Function runs on the same server where the static class was created. Each server has its own "instance" of the static class and all functions that run on this server share this static class.